How to get a backtrace in a Perl script on a not so fatal error?
I get a crash in a situation where I'm trying to iterate over an empty array in a Perl script. The output is
Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at ...

The array is created by a module and I need to get a stacktrace to help find the root of the problem in this module.
However, when running the script with GDB and trying to get a backtrace, I get a "No stack." message. Indeed, after the "undefined value" error, there are some more lines in the script's output, so it seems like the script doesn't completely crash at this point and thus GDB tries to get its backtrace too late. But the script exits a little bit later (which it wouldn't, if the array had been well defined, so in the long run the error leads to a crash). I'm sorry for the fuzzy problem description, but the code is quite complex (for me) and I'm not sure what is actually happening there... Thus, I'm actually only interested in the following question:
Is there a way to enforce a fatal crash at a given position such that GDB will pick it up and generate a backtrace? Kind of tell GDB: "Here's the problematic variable, please show me a backtrace that lead to it"?
edit: Here is a backtrace including C library information, which I could get for a different crash:
(gdb) bt
#0  XQueryExtension (dpy=0x0, name=0x7ffff7e18000 "X-Resource", 
    major_opcode=0x7fffffffc0f4, first_event=0x7fffffffc0f8, 
    first_error=0x7fffffffc0fc) at ../../src/QuExt.c:48
#1  0x00007ffff53ac097 in XInitExtension (dpy=dpy@entry=0x0, 
    name=name@entry=0x7ffff7e18000 "X-Resource") at ../../src/InitExt.c:59
#2  0x00007ffff5205840 in XextAddDisplay (
    extinfo=0x7ffff7e1a110 <_xres_ext_info_data>, dpy=dpy@entry=0x0, 
    ext_name=ext_name@entry=0x7ffff7e18000 "X-Resource", 
    hooks=hooks@entry=0x7ffff7e1a0a0 <xres_extension_hooks>, 
    nevents=nevents@entry=0, data=data@entry=0x0) at ../../src/extutil.c:110
#3  0x00007ffff7e163c9 in find_display (dpy=0x0)
    at /build/libxres-6CIuq8/libxres-1.2.1/src/XRes.c:41
#4  0x00007ffff7e164a6 in XResQueryExtension (dpy=dpy@entry=0x0, 
    event_base_return=event_base_return@entry=0x7fffffffc1c8, 
    error_base_return=error_base_return@entry=0x7fffffffc1cc)
    at /build/libxres-6CIuq8/libxres-1.2.1/src/XRes.c:52
#5  0x00007ffff5ed01dd in init_xres (self=0x55555a04a370)
    at ../libwnck/wnck-handle.c:190
#6  wnck_handle_constructed (object=0x55555a04a370)
    at ../libwnck/wnck-handle.c:208
#7  0x00007ffff6dc3bba in g_object_new_internal (class=0x55555a04a240, 
    params=0x7fffffffc380, n_params=1) at ../../../gobject/gobject.c:2654
#8  0x00007ffff6dc5bc3 in g_object_new_internal (n_params=1, 
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--c
    params=0x7fffffffc380, class=0x55555a04a240)
    at ../../../gobject/gobject.c:2920
#9  g_object_new_valist (object_type=<optimized out>, 
    first_property_name=<optimized out>, 
    var_args=var_args@entry=0x7fffffffc650) at ../../../gobject/gobject.c:2942
#10 0x00007ffff6dc5f4f in g_object_new (object_type=<optimized out>, 
    first_property_name=<optimized out>) at ../../../gobject/gobject.c:2415
#11 0x00007ffff5ebfdfa in _wnck_get_handle () at ../libwnck/util.c:161
#12 wnck_screen_get_default () at ../libwnck/screen.c:562
#13 0x00007ffff7e2fb16 in ffi_call_unix64 () at ../src/x86/unix64.S:104
#14 0x00007ffff7e2c3ef in ffi_call_int (cif=cif@entry=0x7fffffffc950, 
    fn=<optimized out>, rvalue=<optimized out>, avalue=<optimized out>, 
    closure=closure@entry=0x0) at ../src/x86/ffi64.c:673
#15 0x00007ffff7e2f0be in ffi_call (cif=cif@entry=0x7fffffffc950, 
    fn=fn@entry=0x7ffff5ebfdc0 <wnck_screen_get_default>, 
    rvalue=rvalue@entry=0x7fffffffc930, avalue=<optimized out>)
    at ../src/x86/ffi64.c:710
#16 0x00007ffff6bb2c2b in invoke_c_code (info=info@entry=0x55555a046f40, 
    func_pointer=<optimized out>, sp=sp@entry=0x555558aa19e0, ax=ax@entry=1, 
    items=items@entry=4, internal_stack_offset=internal_stack_offset@entry=4, 
    package=<optimized out>, namespace=<optimized out>, 
    function=<optimized out>, mark=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/src/libglib-object-introspection-perl-0.051-1build3/gperl-i11n-invoke-c.c:202
#17 0x00007ffff6bb3aa8 in XS_Glib__Object__Introspection_invoke (
    my_perl=<optimized out>, cv=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/src/libglib-object-introspection-perl-0.051-1build3/GObjectIntrospection.xs:1018
#18 0x00005555556901da in ?? ()
#19 0x000055555568570e in Perl_runops_standard ()
#20 0x00005555555c48ea in Perl_call_sv ()
#21 0x00007ffff6bb0aea in invoke_perl_code (cif=<optimized out>, 
    resp=0x7fffffffd120, args=0x7fffffffcf70, userdata=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/src/libglib-object-introspection-perl-0.051-1build3/gperl-i11n-invoke-perl.c:169
#22 0x00007ffff7e2f641 in ffi_closure_unix64_inner (cif=<optimized out>, 
    fun=<optimized out>, user_data=<optimized out>, rvalue=<optimized out>, 
    reg_args=<optimized out>, argp=0x7fffffffd150 "") at ../src/x86/ffi64.c:899
#23 0x00007ffff7e2fd38 in ffi_closure_unix64 () at ../src/x86/unix64.S:303
#24 0x00007ffff6dd26bd in _g_closure_invoke_va (param_types=0x0, 
    n_params=<optimized out>, args=0x7fffffffd380, instance=0x55555a02a5f0, 
    return_value=0x0, closure=0x555557390320)
    at ../../../gobject/gclosure.c:897
#25 signal_emit_valist_unlocked (instance=instance@entry=0x55555a02a5f0, 
    signal_id=signal_id@entry=239, detail=detail@entry=0, 
    var_args=var_args@entry=0x7fffffffd380) at ../../../gobject/gsignal.c:3424
#26 0x00007ffff6dd27c1 in g_signal_emit_valist (instance=0x55555a02a5f0, 
    signal_id=239, detail=0, var_args=var_args@entry=0x7fffffffd380)
    at ../../../gobject/gsignal.c:3263
#27 0x00007ffff6dd2883 in g_signal_emit (
    instance=instance@entry=0x55555a02a5f0, signal_id=<optimized out>, 
    detail=detail@entry=0) at ../../../gobject/gsignal.c:3583
#28 0x00007ffff6a01f2e in g_application_register (
    application=application@entry=0x55555a02a5f0, 
    cancellable=cancellable@entry=0x0, error=error@entry=0x7fffffffd520)
    at ../../../gio/gapplication.c:2352
#29 0x00007ffff6a024d0 in g_application_real_local_command_line (
    application=0x55555a02a5f0, arguments=0x7fffffffd578, 
    exit_status=0x7fffffffd574) at ../../../gio/gapplication.c:1155
#30 0x00007ffff6a02823 in g_application_run (application=0x55555a02a5f0, 
    argc=<optimized out>, argv=0x0) at ../../../gio/gapplication.c:2681
#31 0x00007ffff7e2fb16 in ffi_call_unix64 () at ../src/x86/unix64.S:104
#32 0x00007ffff7e2c3ef in ffi_call_int (cif=cif@entry=0x7fffffffd7e0, 
    fn=<optimized out>, rvalue=<optimized out>, avalue=<optimized out>, 
    closure=closure@entry=0x0) at ../src/x86/ffi64.c:673
#33 0x00007ffff7e2f0be in ffi_call (cif=cif@entry=0x7fffffffd7e0, 
    fn=fn@entry=0x7ffff6a02720 <g_application_run>, 
    rvalue=rvalue@entry=0x7fffffffd7c0, avalue=<optimized out>)
    at ../src/x86/ffi64.c:710
#34 0x00007ffff6bb2c2b in invoke_c_code (info=info@entry=0x555559f86a90, 
    func_pointer=<optimized out>, sp=sp@entry=0x555558aa19e0, ax=ax@entry=1, 
    items=items@entry=5, internal_stack_offset=internal_stack_offset@entry=4, 
    package=<optimized out>, namespace=<optimized out>, 
    function=<optimized out>, mark=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/src/libglib-object-introspection-perl-0.051-1build3/gperl-i11n-invoke-c.c:202
#35 0x00007ffff6bb3aa8 in XS_Glib__Object__Introspection_invoke (
    my_perl=<optimized out>, cv=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/src/libglib-object-introspection-perl-0.051-1build3/GObjectIntrospection.xs:1018
#36 0x00005555556901da in ?? ()
#37 0x000055555568570e in Perl_runops_standard ()
#38 0x00005555555c3cfd in perl_run ()
#39 0x000055555559963a in main ()


Are you trying to debug Perl interpreter or Perl script? GDB does not support direct Perl scripts debugging, see the list of supported languages at https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/.

I'm trying to debug a script, calling GDB with gdb --args perl /path/to/script

Perl has it's own debugger...

@Shawn Thanks! Will it go into C libraries (included via Glib::Object::Introspection) as well?

@Photon Please show a minimal example of the Perl script, including the place where it enters the C library. If you compile perl with debugging symbols and the C library with debugging symbols, you should be able to debug the C library from GDB. See [mcve] for more information

@HåkonHægland The problem is that I don't fully understand the code, in particular, why it doesn't actually completely crash at the point where it tries to iterate over an empty array. Therefore I am not able to construct a minimal example with exactly the required features. The project in question contains over 10k lines of code in the main file alone. The only thing I could figure out for sure is what I tried to explain in the original question (iteration over an empty array, no complete crash though, so no backtrace in GDB). Really sorry for such incomplete information!

@Photon Have you compiled perl and the C library with debugging symbols? I think you will not get a backtrace unless you do so

@HåkonHægland That's actually a good question. But I'm not at this point yet. Even without debugging symbols GDB usually shows a backtrace with minimal information. I got such backtraces with the script in question for a different crash. But for this particular crash it tells "No stack.", so it doesn't even show the minimal information that is usually shown without debugging symbols. I'd like to get to the point where I am sure that I can get a backtrace in principle before recompiling perl and several libraries with debugging symbols...

@Photon Ok! Anyway, please try to create a minimal example (or at least give some more information), so we can try reproduce.

@HåkonHægland Well, it happens at this loop because $wnck_screen->get_windows_stacked is undefined: https://github.com/shutter-project/shutter/blob/fa324ef66fbeb66dd228317ebd1d015e50c4fb5d/bin/shutter#L8457 And I try to get a backtrace for this library: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libwnck/-/issues/162 But I'm not sure if this actually helps...

Use Carp::Always to get a stack trace for Perl warnings and Perl fatal errors such as the one you are getting.
$ perl <<'.'
use strict;

sub c { my $x; my @a = @$x; }
sub b { c(); }
sub a { b(); }

a();
.
Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at - line 3.

$ perl -MCarp::Always <<'.'
use strict;

sub c { my $x; my @a = @$x; }
sub b { c(); }
sub a { b(); }

a();
.
Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at - line 3.
        main::c() called at - line 4
        main::b() called at - line 5
        main::a() called at - line 7


gdb will debug the executable, which is perl. That might be useful for debugging XS code, but it's not useful for debugging Perl code. Perl has its own debugger, perl -d, for that. Of course, the solution presented above is far simpler.

Thanks for your proposal! Carp::Always is actually already in use but it won't show any debug information from code outside the Perl script (that is, from some of the C libraries in use). Am I getting you right, that the perl debugger will do that and get a stacktrace which includes information about code inside the included C libraries?

The perl -d documentation says in the "Bugs" section: "You cannot get stack frame information or in any fashion debug functions that were not compiled by Perl, such as those from C or C++ extensions." So it looks like it won't help in my case, will it?

I could get what looked like a useful backtrace using GDB in other situations (where it really crashed completely), so GDB works in principle, but now the problem is that GDB gives no backtrace.

Re "Carp::Always is actually already in use but it won't show any debug information from code outside the Perl script", So? You asked a Perl question about a Perl error being given by Perl code.

Re "Am I getting you right, that the perl debugger will do that and get a stacktrace which includes information about code inside the included C libraries?", No, it won't. Again, you asked a Perl question about a Perl error being given by Perl code. You didn't ask how to debug C code.

Re "So it looks like it won't help in my case, will it?", It will help. Because the error comes from Perl code, not a C or C++ extension.

Re "now the problem is that GDB gives no backtrace.", If you were to ask gdb for a backtrace, it would be of Perl running its opcode loop. Not very useful. Again, gdb is to debug binaries while perl -d is for Perl code.

Re "Because the error comes from Perl code, not a C or C++ extension.", Are you sure about it? In the Perl code, an object is defined directly by using a C library through Glib::Object::Introspection. This object has an array as one of its properties, which for some reason is empty. Whatever happens to obtain this array happens in this C library.

That error message is emitted by Perl opcodes when strict refs is enabled. Note that all the files that use it are named pp*.c, which are the files that contain the code of the opcodes.

Now you've lost me, I never heard of opcodes so far... Sorry! I'm trying to find something to read about them but a quick search didn't give a hit which helps to better understand the puzzle. Do you by chance know where I can read more about them, or maybe you could explain how these opcodes relate to the given problem?

Re "Now you've lost me, I never heard of opcodes", Perl code is compiled into a graph of "opcodes", a family of struct types. There's a strong parallel between Perl operators (incl the functions in perlfunc) and Perl opcodes. See the output of perl -MO=Concise,-exec -Mv5.10 -e'my $x = 123; my $y = 456; say $x + $y;' for a representation of the opcodes into which that program is compiled.

With gbd, you'd set a breakpoint on the lines mentioning PL_no_usym in Perl_softref2xv and in S_softref2xv_lite (at least in the blead). But that won't be very useful since the stack trace will just show the Perl opcode loop.

Okay, I cannot claim that I fully understand the concept, but then how to get to the stacktrace of the C libs? Let me attach to the original question a stacktrace which I got using GDB for a different crash, so you can see what I am trying to get.

Added backtrace to the original question now!

Re "but then how to get to the stacktrace of the C libs?", Again, the question is about Perl code, not a C lib. If you have a new question, feel free to ask it. But ask it as a Question. Asking it in the comments of another Question without any detail is not appropriate. Adding an irrelevant stack trace to the Question is not appropriate.

Besides, I already answered that. If you want a strack trace when a certain line is executed, add a breakpoint on it. I even identified the lines.

If you are running a C program that calls perl code somehow in the same process, perhaps this may help https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::GDB::Breakpoint – but you will get perl interpreter stacktrace, not perl code stacktrace.
For the latter try setting PERL5OPT=-MCarp:::Always envvar before calling the C program.
